# Missing Persons Investigations last mission won't trigger

Tags: watch-dogs

When I check my progression it shows me that I am on 6/7 for Missing Persons.  I have been awarded the Wildfire rifle and it is in my inventory.  I also confirmed that I have six audio logs in my inventory and listened to them all once more.

The final mission "Crie for Your Daughter - Eliminate the Finger Paint Killer" doesn't trigger.  I didn't get a map icon over the trailer park in Pawnee.  I ran around the trailer park but that did nothing.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, the answer is simple.  The `Darkness Looms Trophy` mission to complete the Missing Persons arch is not available till after the main story has advanced past the `Hope is a Sad Thing` mission in Pawnee.

Once the Hope is a Sad Thing mission is complete the serial killer will call Aiden and the Missing Persons arch can be completed.

Comment: I believe there's a 2 day limit on self-answering questions.